# What does BandwidthIn and BandwidthOut graph represent for a service?

Tags: memory-leaks, docker, devops, resource-leak, tutum

I have a service and its bandwidth graph looks like this [image]

[image]

What does it represent.? I am using tutum which shows me these graphs.!
Should I worry about it.? Please Explain! Any help is appreciated.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bandwidth is the the amount of data sent (Out) or received (In) in a period of time. Mbps stands for Mega bits per seconds, i.e., how many bits did you send or receive during that past whole second.

I am sure you heard about xxx Mpbs from your internet provider, in which case, it correspond to the maximum speed you can have, but you are not *required* to use the whole bandwidth all the time.

Same thing on Tutum, depending on your hosting provider / instance type you will also have a maximum Mbps bandwidth, but at any given t time, you are using YY Mbps out of your XX Mpbs maximum.

As the graph increase, it simply means that you send/receive more data, which can mean that you have a higher traffic or you are doing some kind of networking activity.

Comment: Does it mean something is wrong in the code, what should be the optimal graph for this.?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing. 1Mbps peak is usually considered low so I wouldn't worry too much. It can be due to traffic, it can be due to code in an expected way, due to code in an unexpected way, due to webscrappers if your service an http service, etc, etc, etc. For reference, a 4g/lte phone does 10Mbps+.